# ffmpeg hardcode subtitles, no subtitles but no output error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ffmpeg

I'm trying to hardcode subtitles for a project I'm working on: https://scriptme.io  an mp4 files using an external SRT subtitles file.
Despite getting a succesful result as output:

```
video:3923kB audio:975kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.344595%
[libx264 @ 0x63b08c0] frame I:9     Avg QP:15.65  size: 31298
[libx264 @ 0x63b08c0] frame P:609   Avg QP:20.37  size:  4283
[libx264 @ 0x63b08c0] frame B:1242  Avg QP:23.74  size:   907
[libx264 @ 0x63b08c0] consecutive B-frames:  3.3% 15.4% 23.1% 58.3%
[libx264 @ 0x63b08c0] mb I  I16..4: 21.5% 54.0% 24.5%
[libx264 @ 0x63b08c0] mb P  I16..4:  1.2%  2.7%  0.3%  P16..4: 18.7%  4.2%  1.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:71.4%
[libx264 @ 0x63b08c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 13.9%  0.6%  0.0%  direct: 0.1%  skip:85.2%  L0:41.5% L1:56.8% BI: 1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x63b08c0] 8x8 transform intra:62.4% inter:86.2%
[libx264 @ 0x63b08c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 36.7% 53.0% 15.0% inter: 2.2% 3.1% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x63b08c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 42% 20% 13% 25%
[libx264 @ 0x63b08c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 33% 15% 28%  3%  4%  6%  4%  5%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x63b08c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 35% 23% 14%  4%  6%  7%  5%  4%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x63b08c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 51% 17% 26%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x63b08c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.2% UV:0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x63b08c0] ref P L0: 69.1%  9.6% 15.1%  6.1%
[libx264 @ 0x63b08c0] ref B L0: 87.2% 10.7%  2.1%
[libx264 @ 0x63b08c0] ref B L1: 97.9%  2.1%
[libx264 @ 0x63b08c0] kb/s:517.69
[aac @ 0x63b3600] Qavg: 257.742
```

However once I play the video with any player, the subtitles aren't there.

This is the command I'm using for the task

```
ffmpeg -i https://some-bucket.s3.region.amazonaws.com/my-video.mp4 -f mp4 -vf subtitles=sub.srt subtitled-video.mp4
```

Comment: Share full log.

Answer (score 0):

This code is for add subtitle and then you have to select the option subtitle (like stream #0:2(und): Subtitle: mov_text)

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i sub.srt -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:s mov_text  subtitled-video.mp4
```

And this option add subtitle to same video, and will have subs for ever, but first you have to change .srt (text subtitle) in .ass (manual graphic editing), you know, text to graph:

```
ffmpeg -i sub.srt sub.ass
```

Then you can create the video with inner subtitles

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "ass=sub.ass" out.mp4
```

Stacks Regards